# WordPress shortcode fails in Custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm creating a theme and i want the user to be able to use shortcodes.
Right now it outputs `[the_shortcode]` and I think I know why but don't know how to fix it.

I load the content of the page not in the conventional way.
Preferably the way is to load `the_content()` function. But the way my template is designed it loads content based upon placement in the hierarchy of pages.

So a parent has a different look then a child.

To do this I load the content with a foreach loop and echo out `$grandchild->post_title`. The page being a grandchild of a parent.

Now the way to fix this, according to the internet, is to use the `apply_filters()` function.
The function expects two parameters and I have no clue on how to fill them:

```
function apply_filters( $tag, $value )
```

This is my function for the shortcode:

```
function output_function(){
    return 'Knees weak, arms are heavy';
}
add_shortcode('output', 'output_function');
```

The shortcode is placed in a page post like this: `['output']`

Any thoughts on how to output page content through the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `the_content`

```
$content = 'some string that has a [output] shortcode';
echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

This filter will make sure all `$content` is parsed like the WordPress editor.
The same like `the_content()`.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you